# how to change the required field of lastname in the checkout billing address form Magento 2

Tags: magento2, php, checkout, cart

Good day people,

I have been trying to change the required field of lastname as not required in the form in the billing address of the checkout page:

[image]

As you can see the field of lastname is out and I used just Company name.

The things that I tried up until now are these:

to the `talons/CheckoutPage/BillingAddress/useBillingAddress.js` I erased the value lastname from the setBillingAddress & updateBillingAddress:

```
 const setBillingAddress = useCallback(() => {
        const {
            firstName,

            country,
            street1,
            street2,
            city,
            region,
            postcode,
            phoneNumber
        } = formState.values;

        updateBillingAddress({
            variables: {
                cartId,
                firstName,

                country,
                street1,
                street2,
                city,
                region,
                postcode,
                phoneNumber,
                sameAsShipping: false
            }
        });
    }, [formState.values, updateBillingAddress, cartId]);
```

to the `talons/CheckoutPage/BillingAddress/billingAddress.gql.js` I did the same:

```
export const SET_BILLING_ADDRESS = gql`
mutation setBillingAddress(
    $cartId: String!
    $firstName: String!
    $street1: String!
    $street2: String
    $city: String!
    $region: String!
    $postcode: String!
    $country: String!
    $phoneNumber: String!
) {
    setBillingAddressOnCart(
        input: {
            cart_id: $cartId
            billing_address: {
                address: {
                    firstname: $firstName
                    street: [$street1, $street2]
                    city: $city
                    region: $region
                    postcode: $postcode
                    country_code: $country
                    telephone: $phoneNumber
                    save_in_address_book: false
                }
            }
        }
    ) @connection(key: "setBillingAddressOnCart") {
        cart {
            id
            billing_address {
                firstname

                country {
                    code
                }
                street
                city
                region {
                    code
                }
                postcode
                telephone
            }
            ...PriceSummaryFragment
            ...AvailablePaymentMethodsFragment
        }
    }
}
${PriceSummaryFragment}
${AvailablePaymentMethodsFragment}
```

`;

I also change the `is_required = 0` in the table `eav_attribute`, `entity_type_id = 2`

And finally I tried to comment the value of lastname in the schema CartAddressInput in my new module, the route of my module is this: `/app/code/MyCompany/AdminUserForms/etc/schema.graphqls`

the route of original module is this: `vendor/magento/module-quote-graph-ql/etc/schema.graphqls`

This is the schema:

```
input CartAddressInput
@doc(
    description: "Defines the billing or shipping address to be applied to the cart."
) {
firstname: String!
    @doc(description: "The first name of the customer or guest.")
# lastname: String!
#     @doc(description: "The last name of the customer or guest.")
company: String
    @doc(
        description: "The company specified for the billing or shipping address."
    )
street: [String!]!
    @doc(
        description: "An array containing the street for the billing or shipping address."
    )
city: String!
    @doc(
        description: "The city specified for the billing or shipping address."
    )
region: String
    @doc(
        description: "A string that defines the state or province of the billing or shipping address."
    )
region_id: Int
    @doc(
        description: "An integer that defines the state or province of the billing or shipping address."
    )
postcode: String
    @doc(
        description: "The ZIP or postal code of the billing or shipping address."
    )
country_code: String!
    @doc(
        description: "The country code and label for the billing or shipping address."
    )
telephone: String
    @doc(
        description: "The telephone number for the billing or shipping address."
    )
save_in_address_book: Boolean
    @doc(
        description: "Determines whether to save the address in the customer's address book. The default value is true."
    )
```

}

I did all of this and I getting the same error:

[image]

Does anyone have any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can define rules for the every file in the JS , It will work.

Comment: what do you mean?
In the JS file inside each module in magento?

Comment: You can override the form or You can create JS with the path view/base/web and use that js rules.

Comment: can you send me a path of a file to see as example please?

Comment: or maybe just a documentation that explains how?